# What happens inside SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The default implementation for Login in a asp.net MVC5 Web App is the following:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I want to remove this logic to add just an if condition like this:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
      if (model.Email == "abc@abc.com")
      {
       //case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
      }
    }
```

What else do I need to set to make this email adress authenticated in web application? Does "SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync" sets a cookie or useridentity variable to be recognized by app? 
I'd want to know what I need to set to have my user signed in(display email at top right corner, etc.)